# Data analysis: problem with mapping and correcting typos in column

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I've been reviewing data for a project on jupyter and I was hoping to map some data to fit it in a specific category of company.

In the end, I used a big if loop but the problem as expected is I cant parse each individual cells using a column so is there any other better way to do it? the code I got wasn't functional in the first place so I tried to improve it with my little knowledge of python.

So I wanna pick a value in SicCodes column compare it into the mapping and basically get the name as an output.
I thought as a first approach to get my most simple parsing of data with if loop and then improve it later on.
But indeed, I can't shove data frame into my little to_code_range so I thought about doing it with a for loop, but isn't successful at the moment.

Would anyone have a good idea on how to improve that?

```
mappings = [
    (1000, 9990, 'Agriculture'),
    (10000, 14990, 'Mining'),
    (15000, 17990, 'Construction'),
    (18000, 19990, 'not used'),
    (20000, 39990, 'Manufacturing'),
    (40000, 49990, 'Utility Services'),
    (50000, 51990, 'Wholesale Trade'),
    (52000, 59990, 'Retail Trade'),
    (60000, 69200, 'Financials'),
    (70000, 90040, 'Services'),
    (91000, 97290, 'Public Administration'),
    (98000, 99990, 'Nonclassifiable'),
]

"""errors = set()
def to_code_range(i): 
    if type(i) != int: 
        print("Pas un int")
    if i=="None Supplied": 
        return np.nan
    code = int(i)
    for code_from, code_to, name in mappings: 
        if (code<=code_to)&(code>=code_from): 
            return name
        errors.add(code)
        return np.nan"""

def to_code_range(valeur): 
    if type(valeur) != int: print("Pas un int")
    code = int(valeur)
    if (code<1000): return np.nan
    if (code>=1000)&(code<=9990): return "Agriculture"
    if (code>=10000)&(code<=14990): return "Mining" 
    if (code>=10000)&(code<=14990): return "Mining"
    if (code>=15000)&(code<=17990): return "Construction"
    if (code>=18000)&(code<=19990): return "not used"
    if (code>=20000)&(code<=39990): return "Manufacturing"
    if (code>=40000)&(code<=49990): return "Utility Services"
    if (code>=50000)&(code<=51990): return "Wholesale Trade"
    if (code>=52000)&(code<=59990): return "Retail Trade"
    if (code>=60000)&(code<=69200): return "Financials"
    if (code>=70000)&(code<=90040): return "Services"
    if (code>=91000)&(code<=97290): return "Public Administration"
    if (code>=98000)&(code<=99990): return "Nonclassifiable"
    else :return np.nan
        
#report['SICCode.SicText_1'] = to_code_range(report["SicCodes"])
for i in report['SicCodes']: report['SICCode.SicText_1'][i] = to_code_range(i)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o15iY.jpg)

if loop and for loop
but I have an error as an output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mappings = [
    (1000, 9990, 'Agriculture'),
    (10000, 14990, 'Mining'),
    (15000, 17990, 'Construction'),
    (18000, 19990, 'not used'),
    (20000, 39990, 'Manufacturing'),
    (40000, 49990, 'Utility Services'),
    (50000, 51990, 'Wholesale Trade'),
    (52000, 59990, 'Retail Trade'),
    (60000, 69200, 'Financials'),
    (70000, 90040, 'Services'),
    (91000, 97290, 'Public Administration'),
    (98000, 99990, 'Nonclassifiable'),
]

def to_code_range(valeur): 
    if type(valeur) != int: 
        print("Pas un int")
        return np.nan
    for code_from, code_to, name in mappings:
        if code_from <= valeur <= code_to:
            return name
    return np.nan

# Assuming 'report' is a DataFrame with a column 'SicCodes'
report = pd.DataFrame({
    'SicCodes': [1000, 15000, 20000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 70000, 91000, 98000]
})

report['SICCode.SicText_1'] = report['SicCodes'].apply(to_code_range)

print(report)
```

Output of interpreter

```
   SicCodes      SICCode.SicText_1
0      1000            Agriculture
1     15000           Construction
2     20000          Manufacturing
3     40000       Utility Services
4     50000        Wholesale Trade
5     60000             Financials
6     70000               Services
7     91000  Public Administration
8     98000        Nonclassifiable
```

Comment: Thanks for your time answering it, it looks legit but i basically did an overall data wrangling to make sure it fits.